# How to activate some lights after a short delay in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, pls

I want the lights to be activated a little after "me" has been activated.

```
public class LightsOut : MonoBehaviour

{

    public GameObject NextTrigger;

    public GameObject Voiceline;

    public GameObject Me;

    public GameObject Lights;



    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            NextTrigger.SetActive(true);
            Voiceline.SetActive(true);
            Me.SetActive(false);
            Lights.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
StartCoroutine(ActivateLight())
```

And add a method

```
IEnumerator ActivateLight()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    Lights.SetActive(true);
}
```